# С помощью Python cоздать новый лист в уже имеющемся Excel файле

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, openpyxl

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно с помощью `Python` открывать `Excel` файл (а если такого файла нет, то создать сначала его) и при каждом запуске скрипта создавать в данном файле новый лист и записывать в него некоторую текстовую информацию?

Comment: Вот пример: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/f492320d33021c467a4e3e88a478dee4f70ca59e/excel__openpyxl__xlwt/load__or_create__append_new_sheets__xlsx.py

Comment: @gil9red благодарю, все получилось!

Comment: Раз мой вариант вам подошел, а в нем не было pandas, а вопрос был закрыт как дубликат вопроса по pandas+excel, то можно попробовать его переоткрыть, а, @MaxU? :)

Comment: @gil9red, переоткрыл ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Пример](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/f492320d33021c467a4e3e88a478dee4f70ca59e/excel__openpyxl__xlwt/load__or_create__append_new_sheets__xlsx.py) создания документа и заполнения листов:

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.writer.excel import save_workbook

columns = ['Name', 'Age', 'Course']
rows = [
    ['Vasya', '16', 1],
    ['Anya', '17', 2],
    ['Inna', '16', 1],
]

FILE_NAME = 'excel.xlsx'

try:
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(FILE_NAME)
except:
    wb = openpyxl.Workbook()

    # Удаление листа, создаваемого по умолчанию, при создании документа
    for sheet_name in wb.sheetnames:
        sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name(sheet_name)
        wb.remove_sheet(sheet)

# Создание нового листа, названия новых листов будут автоматически инкрементироваться: Students, Students1, Students2, и т.п.
ws = wb.create_sheet('Students')

for i, value in enumerate(columns, 1):
    ws.cell(row=1, column=i).value = value

for i, row in enumerate(rows, 2):
    for j, value in enumerate(row, 1):
        ws.cell(row=i, column=j).value = value

save_workbook(wb, FILE_NAME)
```

После пары запусков:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]